# within sequence of $n^2$ there need not be a monotonic subsequence of length $n+1$

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I am reading the book "Ramsey theory on the integers" by Bruce M.Landman and Aaron Robertson. There they proved that within any sequence of $n^2+1$ numbers there exists a monotonic subsequence of length $n+1$ by using Pigeonhole principle.

But I am trying to prove the following: given a sequence of only $n^2$ numbers, there need not be a monotonic subsequence of length $n+1$.

I find the following sequence for $n=2$: $1, 0, 6, -1$
But I can't find even for $n=3$ and not able to generalize for arbitrary $n$

Could any help please?

Comment: Possible Typo; The title says "there not be".

Comment: Reread topic please

Comment: Connection with Erdös-Szekeres theorem (http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/subseq4proofs.pdf) ?

Comment: You may find the following You Tube video from Numberphile titled "Order From Chaos" interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwIAfkuXc5A

Answer (score 2):

$3,6,9,2,5,8,1,4,7$ right? This should work. Generalisation should be straightforward, and if it isn't I'd be happy to explain. Just comment. Okay, for general $n$ take

$n,2n,3n,4n,\cdots,n^2,n-1,2n-1,3n-1,n^2-1,n-2,\cdots,\cdots,1,n+1,2n+1,3n+1,\cdots,n^2-n+1$

**EDIT:** Take $n$ APs, each of length $n$ with common difference $n$. The first starts at $n$, the second at $n-1$, the third at $n-2$ etc all the way down to 1. Then we concatenate them.

Comment: How to generalize it for arbitrary $n$? I have tried to consider permutations of $(n^2)!$ of numbers $\{1,2,..., n^2-1, n^2\}$

Comment: Can you explain the pattern of your sequence? It seems to me bit abstruse.

Comment: How you conceive that example so fast? I have thought about that one day and no results :(

Comment: I've thought about it for a bit a while ago when I was trying to improve the bound as well.

Comment: Are you also reading the book which I mentioned above? I began to interest in Ramsey theory, recently

Comment: I'm not reading that book. Sounds interesting though. Plus a related Ramsey theory question: Prove that in a sequence of abc+1 (not necessarily distinct) integers, we either have a strictly increasing sequence of a+1 integers, a strictly decreasing sequence of b+1 or a constant sequence of length c+1. Good luck with that one.

Comment: Nice question :) I need some time for that. I hope that i can solve that one.

Comment: Dear Wen. Let me ask you question: How to prove rigorously that above sequence has not monotonic subsequence length $n+1$? This is not so clear to me. I have tried to do it by contradiction but I stuck

Comment: Colouring arguments, I guess. Colour 1,2,3,...,n one colour, n+1,n+2,...,2n another, 2n+1,...,3n another colour etc. If there exists an increasing sequence then it must go from the first colour to the second colour to the third etc. i.e it must always move up a colour.